# tensorflow - tf.Session() don't create new session

Tags: tensorflow

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess)
    print(sess.graph)

tf.reset_default_graph()
sess2 = tf.Session()
with sess2.as_default():
    print(sess)
    print(sess.graph)
```

Output:

```py
<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x7f53254d7080>
<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x7f53251c7e10>

<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x7f53254d7080>
<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x7f53251c7e10>
```

It looks like `sess` and `sess2` are the same object. Why `tf.Session()` do not create a new session in this code? What's going on in `as_default()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing `sess` object in both cases.